# Codeigniter Fatal error when calling css less functions

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, less

I have a problem when I call this function I am getting the following error:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'load error: failed to find test.less' in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\application\views\lessc.inc.php:1818"

```
<?php 
require('lessc.inc.php');
$less = new lessc;
echo $less->checkedCompile("test.less","hoba.css");
?>
```

and I have test.less, hoba.css and lessc.inc.php all in the views folder

Comment: is lessc class?try to load as `$less = new lessc()` or write your lessc.inc.php file.

Comment: http://leafo.net/lessphp/ I took the syntax from the quick start section

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
<?php 
require('lessc.inc.php');
$less = new lessc;
echo $less->checkedCompile(site_url()."application/views/test.less",site_url()."application/views/hoba.css");
?>
```

Comment: Try and put your complete directory structure, specially all the folders and files in your views folder, and also the location of the file which is running less

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the lessphp class, but try putting the "less.inc.php" (and any other files associated with it) in application/third_party. Next create a file "less.php" in application/libraries. In that file, paste the following:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once APPPATH."/third_party/less.inc.php"; 

class Less extends lessc { 
    public function __construct() { 
        parent::__construct(); 
    } 
}
```

In the controller where you need it, something like:

```
$this->load->library('less');
$data['css'] = $this->less->checkedCompile(base_url()."path/to/test.less",base_url()."path/to/hoba.css");
$this->load->view('your_view', $data);
```

Also, it looks like you're storing .less and .css files in the application/views folder. You should store these outside the application folder, in a folder called "assets/css" or something similar.